# is fullpath of images in my website decrese the loading of pages?

Tags: html

one of my friend tell me that that if i uses full path for images sourse ie: www.mysite/products/new/images/xyz.jpg instesd of "images/xyz.jpg" will deacrese of loading of my page beacuse request will take more time to answered.

is this correct. I am using fullpath for all of my iamges.

Comment: I would ask your friend to see a test that benchmarks this.

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't make any difference.

You can test it using Fiddler, Wireshark, etc. - look at the HTTP requests and you'll see that they're identical.

<sub>(Note for completeness: This answer might not be right if you're doing something tricky with `<base href>` or similar, but I guess from your question that you're not.  :-)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Request itself will be the same time. But remember that fullpath as more chars... So the HTML is a little bigger.